# How to use IP_TRANSPARENT to avoid too-many-TIME_WAIT

Tags: tcp, socket

I've heard that we can avoid the issue of "too many TIME_WAIT" with the help of `IP_TRANSPARENT` in TCP/IP connection. In this way, it seems that a `RST` is used to disconnect, instead of `FIN` and `ACK`.

But I don't quite understand how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Note that, since you didn't mentionned which OS you're working with, i'll assume that it's GNU/Linux (which maybe a bad assumption since this is "UNIX & Linux").

#### Tweaking kernel behaviour

Under Linux, tweaking your TCP stack at runtime is usually achieved using `sysctl` and/or procfs.

So you probably should start by having a look to:

- tcp(7) manpage
- Files under `Documentation/sysctl/` on your kernel source code. (You can also use [this site](https://sysctl-explorer.net/net/ipv4/)).

To see if there's some options/parameter that would allow that.

#### One step further

After a quick look at kernel source code ( [`net/ipv4/tcp.c`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/net/ipv4/tcp.c) ) it looks that the use of FIN flag to shutdown is "hardcoded" and can't be changed... sorry.

Maybe you can try to write a patch to change this behaviour... but i wouldn't push in production server such a patch ;-)

#### To conclude

It looks that there's no way to do what you asked for.

Nevertheless, maybe you can mitigate the "too many TIME_WAIT" issue by tweaking some other parameters such as net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout (also reachable at `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_fin_timeout`).

Note that, if you have the hand on your application source code, you can also tweak its behaviour using `setsockopt()` on the created socket.

Comment: I was told that using `IP_TRANSPARENT` to send a packet to the server and the server will regard this as a new incoming so it will send back an `ACK`. However, this `ACK` will send to the client, who is willing to close the connection. And this `ACK` will make the client send a `RST` to the server. In the end, the connection is shutdown.

Comment: you see it might be reasonable, but I can't how figure it out with all details.

Comment: Use `IP_TRANSPARENT` where ?

Comment: You see this is what I don't know and what I'm trying to figure out... What I've known is that it might simulate a RST attack to avoid TIME_WAIT with the help of `IP_TRANSPARENT`.

Comment: Source ? Cause `IP_TRANSPARENT` is a socket option which is actually used for proxying ... (see [man 7 ip](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html)). Anyway, this option is available with `AF_INET` socket type, and this socket type doesn't allow you to set headers by yourself ... so it looks like you're looking the wrong direction...

Comment: Well, it came from a Chinese article(http://www.52im.net/thread-1004-1-1.html). I don't think this article is wrong. If you want, you can google-translate the fifth paragraph: `5、清掉TIME_WAIT的奇技怪巧`

Answer (score 0):

Not IP_TRANSPARENT, but here might be a different solution to your issue.

(Posting as an answer rather than as a comment so that the code block is readable)

If your Linux machine is a client, rather than a server, then you might experiment with the following in /etc/sysctl.conf one at a time or together, then `sysctl -p`.  Please look into what each one does to see if each is appropriate for your use.

```
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 2000 65535
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 1
```

Great article explaining the gory details: https://vincent.bernat.ch/en/blog/2014-tcp-time-wait-state-linux